# Prevent an input from submitting

Tags: jquery, html

I have an `input` box where users can type their Zipcode to see if their area is covered:

```
<form method="" action="">
    <input id="zipcode" type="text" />
    <p>Enter ZIP Code</p>
</form>
```

I'm then checking what's typed against a list of ZIP codes with jQuery:

```
var zipcodelist = ['12345','90210','12346','12347'];

function validateZipCode() {
  return $.inArray($('#zipcode').val(), zipcodelist) > -1;
  //true means the zip code is in the list, false it is not
}


  $('#zipcode').keyup(function() {
      if( $('#zipcode').val().length == 5 ) {              
        if (!validateZipCode()) {
              // sorry, zip code is not allowed
              $('#zipcode').addClass('red');
              $('p').text('Zipcode not found in the list.');
        } else {
              // this zip code is allowed
              $('#zipcode').removeClass('red');
              $('p').text('Zipcode was found in the list!');
        }
     }
  });
```

Depending on if it's a match, the text inside `<p></p>` will change instantly, this all works fine, but my question is:

How can I prevent the input from being submitted? When the enter key is pressed the form submits and the page refreshes, I'd like to stop that from happening and only allow text to be entered but not submitted.

I removed the name attribute as advised elsewhere but the page still reloads when the enter key is pressed.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3a98f/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent the form from ever submitting by capturing and preventing the `submit` event. Let's identify your form as "zipform":

```
<form method="" action="" id="zipform">
```

Now we can attach the event handler:

```
$(function() { // DOM-ready handler
    $('#zipform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The form doesn't seem to serve a purpose(but will submit non the less), I'd remove it or replace it with a div

```
<div>
    <input id="zipcode" type="text" />
    <p>Enter your ZIP code</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need a form ? Can't you just use a input field with onChange event ?

```
<input id="zipcode" type="text" onChange="validateSubmission()" />
<p>Enter ZIP Code</p>
```

And you can use pure JS to check zipCode and modify "p" element.